# Looking for a word that means "not requiring permission"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I was thinking maybe, free to use but I'm not sure. Is there any one-word alternative?

Preferably an adjective.

For example, some user information is confidential and you need permission to access it. I need a word for user information that doesnt require permission. So the sentence would read: _____ user information

Comment: Give a sample sentence. More context would be helpful.

Comment: Probably "open", but as TR says, we need to know how you'll use it.

Comment: What @TRomano said. In some circumstances ***unregulated*** would work, but there are other words more suited to other contexts.

Comment: Please see my edit, I can add more clarification if needed

Comment: "Unrestricted user information"

Comment: unregulated could be the closest related to 'not requiring permission'.  'Internet is unregulated' means 'free access' whereas 'Internet is open' is vague, I feel.

Answer (score 3):

**"public"** or **"unrestricted"** - as mentioned in one comment - will fit.

> public (adj)
>
> - "exposed to general view, open" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/public)
> - "open or accessible to all" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/public)
>
> "The government has allowed public access to the documents."

Comment: +1 for public, likely the most common word for this type of information in computer software

Comment: *public information*. The OP's word "user" is neither here nor there (we are not a computer term naming service ;)

Answer (score 2):

I owe this to @Dan Bron: [open](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/meaning-of-open.html) is more fitting to IT and online usage.Thus **open** user information; allowing access.
Synonyms:   not shut, not closed, unlocked, unsecured.